# Algebra of Propositional Logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How can I rewrite the following propositions in their simplest equivalent forms

i.e. Least atomic propositions

1. $(p \land \neg p) \Rightarrow \neg p$
2. $\neg ((p \land\neg p) \Rightarrow \neg q) $
3. $\neg ((p \land q) \Rightarrow r)$

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As $p\land\neg p = \bot$:

$$\bot \to \neg p == \top\lor\neg p == \top$$

1. $\top$ (simple closed form)
2. $\bot$
3. $\neg((p\land q)\Rightarrow r)$

Answer (score 0):

The third one can be simplified to $p \land q \land \neg r$:

$$\neg (( p \land q) \rightarrow r) \Leftrightarrow \text{ (Implication)}$$

$$\neg (\neg (p \land q) \lor r) \Leftrightarrow \text{ (DeMorgan)}$$

$$\neg \neg (p \land q) \land \neg r \Leftrightarrow \text{ (Double Negation)}$$

$$(p \land q) \land \neg r \Leftrightarrow \text{ (Association)}$$

$$p \land q \land \neg r$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. Are you able to explain the steps please? I am new to discrete Mathematics.

Comment: @KingGeorge I added the steps to my answer.

Comment: Bram28 thanks a lot for this

Comment: @KingGeorge You're welcome!